# How to make Tomcat wait until web application finishes?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jersey

I have a Java web application, packaged as a "war" and deployed in `Tomcat`. The application uses `Jersey` to implement REST web services.

This application sometimes updates a text (XML) file. I guess that if `Tomcat` is stopped while the application is still updating this file, the file may be corrupted. In order to prevent the file corruption I would like `Tomcat` to wait until the file is closed before the exit. Now I wonder how to implement it.

So, my question is how to make `Tomcat` wait until a web application finishes.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) is particular the context Destroyed method.

**Notification that the servlet context is about to be shut down.**

```
  void  contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should use some servlet life-cycle methods. However I do not use servles directly. I use `Jersey`.

Comment: one caveat, as far as I can tell, is that the `destroy()` method in a `HttpServlet` and similar aren't guaranteed to run to completion. That is, the Servlet container (i.e. Tomcat) will give your servlet a heads-up and call `destroy()` but it may then go on and simply stop without waiting for the `destroy()` to complete.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a different approach in your case (this may not be an answer to your question, but a proposal for your case).

Write the new xml file in a temporal one (conf.xml.tmp), so you still have the original one (conf.xml) untouched.

Once finished generating the xml, just move the newly generated one (conf.xml.tmp) on top off   the original(conf.xml).

(You can also make a copy of the original for backup purposes).

This way, if tomcat stops while processing the xml generation you will always have a working xml.

The key here is that moving a file in the same disk is somehow an "atomic" operation, it will be done or not, but it will be not done  half done.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your shutdown script to take care of this. Make sure that file is in consistent state and then call shutdown.

You can check if file write is under process then sleep the script for say 5 min and then call shutdown.sh/shutdown.bat script.

Apart from this you can also do at java level; but i will prefer controlling it externally. This way you can modify it independent of your core application.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer solution in Java.